# Custom SQL queries in Directus

Tags: sql, directus

Let's say I have this kind of MySQL database structure :

Menu :

```
id  name
 3  Tartiflette
 4  Lasagne
```

Ingredient :

```
id  name        price
15  Carrot      2.00    
39  Garlic      3.00    
40  Reblochon   5.00    
55  Onion       1.00
```

Menu_ingredient :

```
id  ingredient_id   menu_id quantity
4   15              4       2
5   55              4       1
6   39              4       1
7   40              3       2
8   55              3       3
```

Resa_menu :

```
id  resa_id menu_id people
 1  1       4       3
 2  1       3       2
```

Resa :

```
id
1
```

How could I get all the ingredients from one reservation, using one query parameter with the items/ endpoint ?

I tried the query using items/resa_menu?fields=*.* (and some other combinations, but out of luck).

I also set up an SQL View (virtual table) getting all info needed with a query, but this kind of SQL doesn't seem to be fetched by Directus.

```
SELECT 
  ingredient.name as ing_name,
  (resa_menu.people * ingredient.price) as price,
  (resa_menu.people * menu_ingredient.quantity) as quantity 
FROM resa_menu 
INNER JOIN menu             ON menu.id = resa_menu.menu_id 
INNER JOIN resa             ON resa.id = resa_menu.resa_id 
INNER JOIN menu_ingredient  ON menu_ingredient.menu_id = menu.id 
INNER JOIN ingredient       ON ingredient.id = menu_ingredient.ingredient_id 
GROUP BY ingredient.id;
```

Expected output :

```
ing_name       price  quantity
Carrot         6.00   6
Garlic         9.00   3
Reblochon      10.00  4
Onion          3.00   3
```

The specific goal here is to get a summary of all ingredients needed for the reservation (combining all menus, multiplying quantity by number of people). But my question is more generic on : how can you do multiple JOINs like in this query with Directus API ?

Many thanks for the help!

Comment: share sample data of each table and expected output

Comment: I will... but basically I would just need to do a query with INNER JOIN on all of those tables, like :

SELECT 
 resa_menu.id,
 menu.name, 
 ingredient.name, 
 (resa_menu.people * ingredient.price)    as price, 
 (resa_menu.people * menu_ingredient.quantity)  as quantity
FROM resa_menu
INNER JOIN menu      ON menu.id = resa_menu.menu_id
INNER JOIN resa      ON resa.id = resa_menu.resa_id
INNER JOIN menu_ingredient  ON menu_ingredient.menu_id = menu.id
INNER JOIN ingredient     ON ingredient.id = menu_ingredient.ingredient_id
WHERE resa_menu.id = 1
GROUP BY ingredient.id

Comment: @Romin post it on your question not in comment and shample data and expected output will help to get faster solution in SO

Comment: @zay Thanks for the tip, I updated my question with specific details.

Comment: @Roman check the answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think what you mean is you're requesting the endpoint `/items/Resa_menu` and doing `*.*` is returning `Menu_ingredient` related data, however you would like a list of ingredients returned too? for this, would you not just change your fields query to `*.*.*` to get three levels of relations?

Or is it that the `?fields=*.*` simply isn't working at all?

Comment: Also make sure you have the relational fields setup! The relationships won't work if they haven't been setup

Comment: @Rijk thank you, that was exactly my problem. I think this would need to be added to the doc as this is not obvious? Thank you also Shea.

Answer (score 0):

use left join and you does not need group by

```
          select i.name,(i.price* coalesce(rm.people,1)) as price,
             (mi.quantity*coalesce(rm.people,1)) as quantity
            from Ingredient i left join 
            Menu_ingredient mi on i.id =mi.ingredient_id
            left join Resa_menu rm on mi.menu_id =rm.menu_id
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply and for your time @Zaynul. My question was more on how to reproduce this SQL query on Directus API endpoints.

Comment: @Romain does not this query provide your expected result that you mentioned in question